# Drill down chart transition from parent to child data

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, charts, drilldown

I have created a drill down chart in ASP.net using C# in Microsoft Visual Studio. I would like to find out, is there a way to slow down the transition from parent data to child data.

In other words, If a user clicks parent data on a column chart, at the moment it instantly drills down to the child data. I would like to slow this transition down from an instant to maybe a delay of 1 second. Is there a command or statement to follow in order to slow that transition.

Could someone guide me or direct me in the correct direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably want to look at jQuery's transitions.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, I shall start learning jQuery specially the fade effect. Much appreciated.